# localStorage data store time

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using localStorage in jQM and PhoneGap. If I don't delete localStorage manually, how long  would it be stored? When it is deleted?

I would like to know how it works on mobile devices running Android and iOS. I found an opinion that iOS browser clears it occasionally, is that true?

Comment: [Depends on the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9949361/575527). Different browsers treat localStorage differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The localstorage is persistent. It will be stored until you uninstall the application or clear it manually.

Comment: Is it true also on the new iOS?

Comment: Yes, Phonegap fixed the localstorage to be persistent for IOS 5.1