# Does HTML5 localStorage persist across browser instances?

Tags: html, local-storage

I had a similar question [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948284/how-persistent-is-localstorage) but the answers seem a bit cryptic and I'm still not quite "getting" `localStorage`.

1. If I save data to localStorage, and the user closes the browser, does that data get wiped out? Or is it still accessible when they open up a new browser instance?
2. Is localStorage data available to all instances of a browser, or does each browser instance (say, for whatever reason, the user has 5 Firefox instances opened) get its own localStorage?
3. When a user flushes all cookies & session data, does localStorage also get wiped out?

Answer (score 6):

1. If I save data to localStorage, and the user closes the browser, does that data get wiped out? Or is it still accessible when they open up a new browser instance?

- No, the data are persisted and aren't expired until you remove or clear them.
- If you want the data removed when the users close the browser use sessionStorage instead.
- No data persisted in private mode (incognito mode)

2. Is localStorage data available to all instances of a browser, or does each browser instance (say, for whatever reason, the user has 5 Firefox instances opened) get its own localStorage?

- It shares data across the instances of a specific browser, for instance, Firefox tabs/instances share the same data but Chrome doesn't share the data with Firefox.
- It also depends on the browser mechanism:

- Chrome allows adding users, so tabs belong to one user share the same data.
- Data in private mode will be cleared after the browser is closed.

3. When a user flushes all cookies & session data, does localStorage also get wiped out?

- No, it is only wiped out if you clear localStorage.

Answer (score 4):

Local Storage is persistant in different tabs/windows when application is opened from same domain. 5MB storage per Domain is provided. LocalStrorage can be wiped only when u remove it manualy by LocalStorage.clear(); For more on info on html5 local storage please visit :[LOCALSTORAGE in html5](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html)

Comment: I think this is misleading. Local storage persists in different tabs/windows when using the same browser on the same machine. It does not persisted across a domain.