# Change selected option

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following select:

```
        <select id="sitestyle" name="stil">
            <option value="blue">Blå</option>
            <option value="green">Grön</option>
            <option value="red">Röd</option>
            <option value="pink">Rosa</option>                
        </select>
```

I'm saving the value the user has selected to `localStorage`. Say the user selects `value="pink"` and it is then saved to the `localStorage`, user closes browser and opens again i want `value="pink"` to be selected automatically. Currently it is always `value="blue"` regardless of what is saved in the `localStorage`.

Can't use jQuery/Ajax but javascript is fine.

*edit*

I have the following JS:

```
function setStyleFromStorage(){
    style = localStorage.getItem("style");
    document.getElementById('css_style').setAttribute('href', style);
    if(style == "blue"){
        document.getElementById("sitestyle").selectedIndex() = 0;
    }else if(style == "green"){
        document.getElementById("sitestyle").selectedIndex() = 1;
    }else if(style == "red"){
        document.getElementById("sitestyle").selectedIndex() = 2;
    }else if(style == "pink"){
        document.getElementById("sitestyle").selectedIndex() = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you've done so far?, js code, fiddle?

Comment: May be helpful to know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948284/how-persistent-is-localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to change select box value.

```
function setStyleFromStorage(){
    if(localStorage.style){
        document.getElementById("sitestyle").value = localStorage.style;
    }
}
document.getElementById("sitestyle").onchange = function(){
     localStorage.style = this.value;  
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/95KgW/4/)