# LocalStorage limitations

Tags: cordova, devextreme

I need to save properties for my app and I'been looking at LocalStorage to do so, but I've read in some places that it is persistent and in some places that it isnt.

```
DATA_STORAGE_KEY: 'velocity-customerdata',
```

I have a data storage key that I need to access everytime to app opens to gain the saved data about the customer, such as their account ID so they don't have to login again.  Is localstorage the best method for this?  in C# I've always just used the application properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948284/how-persistent-is-localstorage

Answer (score 0):

If you seek for more persistent, i suggest you use sqlite cordova plugin. It's local database in your phone.

https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

How to install it

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin
```