# kendo grid localstorage persistence

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, html, kendo-ui

i saw that new kendo grid have built-in implemented filter persistence with `localStorage`.

```
$(function () {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    $("#save").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage["kendo-grid-options"] = kendo.stringify(grid.getOptions());
    });

    $("#load").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var options = localStorage["kendo-grid-options"];
        if (options) {
            grid.setOptions(JSON.parse(options));
        }
    });
});
```

But is the `localStorage` implemented by cookies?
How does it works, when `getOptions` and `setOptions` are called?

Comment: Maybe you can find some useful information in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948284/how-persistent-is-localstorage)

Comment: Do a search for "html5 web storage" and read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were refering to "setItem(key,value)" and "getItem(key)".
the setItem function is used for saving the value to the local storage and you will use the getItem() to get that value back by providing the key you supplied when saving.