# is localstorage also user specific by default?

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, local-storage

I am storing some data in the local storage using

```
localstorage.setItem("key","value")
```

I understand that localstorage is browser specific, now will this value remain  even after i login as different user (sharepoint) in the same browser?

as far as i know **localStorage is persistent until user clears it**

and i read in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948284/how-persistent-is-localstorage) that

> Duration
>
> In DOM Storage it is not possible to specify an expiration period for
>   any of your data. All expiration rules are left up to the user. In the
>   case of Mozilla, most of those rules are inherited from the
>   Cookie-related expiration rules. Because of this you can probably
>   expect most of your DOM Storage data to last at least for a meaningful
>   amount of time.

So does this mean that local storage is only browser specific? ie even if login as different user in sharepoint, the localstorage values will still remain if i use the same browser? (given that i dont clear it in log out/log in actions in sharepoint)

Comment: Do you mean a "browser user" like in recent chrome versions or a php session user?

Comment: no not browser users, i am looking for sharepoint users
Thanks for asking i will add this detail to question

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that localstorage is browser specific, now will this value remain even after i login as different user in the same browser?

Yes.
Definitely.

It has nothing to do with php sessions or the like. Nothing.
LocalStorage is attached to the browser. Log in or log out, has no effect on localStorage.

> even if login as different user, the localstorage values will still remain if i use the same browser?

Yes.

Comment: In most cases, clear storage after sign out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear

Comment: If your question is 'how to clear localStorage', AJCodez points the right link: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap browser storage with your own interface. It can have expiration by setting a timestamp on writes and checking it on reads.

```
var Storage = {
  get: function (key) {
    var item = localStorage.getItem(key)
    if (item) {
      var entry = JSON.parse(item)
      if (entry.expires && Date.now() > entry.expires) {
        localStorage.removeItem(key)
      } else {
        return entry.data
      }
    }
  },

  set: function (key, value, expires) {
    var entry = { data: value }
    if (expires) { entry.expires = expires }
    var item = JSON.stringify(entry) 
    localStorage.setItem(key, item)
  },
}
```

Comment: "(and you should)" Only add complexity when needed :)

Comment: Just because something is a design pattern doesnt mean you should use it whenever possible and it is still adding another layer (read complexity) which you should only do if necessary.

Comment: Ok will take out opinion, but i use local storage facade every single time in my own projects to keep code simple