# Use local storage for in app purchases with app updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage

I'm developing an app with ionic/cordova and I'm using local storage for the inApp products. Is it safe to use it and does the saved data persist even after a app update?
I have to be really sure.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Similar question: [How persistent is localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948284/how-persistent-is-localstorage)
localstorage does persist and stores the data with no expiration date. However I would recommend to store the purchase data online, and sync it with localstorage once in a while. The user can delete the local storage manually, and then the data is lost. Retrieving it from your online cloud is therefore necessary.