# How can I save setting of my menu_toggle using cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, toggle

I want to toggle my menu and save its settings in the cookie. Here is my Jquery code for toggle button:

**My HTML**

```
  <div class="nav toggle">
  <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  </div>
```

**My Code**

```
 var $MENU_TOGGLE = $('#menu_toggle')
 $MENU_TOGGLE.on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked - menu toggle');

    if ($BODY.hasClass('nav-md')) {
        $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('li.active ul').hide();
        $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('li.active').addClass('active-sm').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('li.active-sm ul').show();
        $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('li.active-sm').addClass('active').removeClass('active-sm');
    }

$BODY.toggleClass('nav-md nav-sm');

setContentHeight();
 });
```

Comment: It's need to be cookie? Maybe localStorage is the solution.
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage

Comment: What's the issue here? Are you asking how to create a cookie with JavaScript?

Comment: @RafaelGadottiBachovas yes I know. But I do not want to store it in my database. In that way, I have to check every time from the database that which setting current user has.

Comment: @Volem Exactly.

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq LocalStorage is stored in the user memory and not in database.

Comment: localStorage.setItem('menuToogle', 1);
localStorage.getItem('menuToogle');

Comment: you want the returning user to find the toggle controls as he left them? if so you have to [create a cooky](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) store values that allow you to use a function that after reading the cooky (if it exists) then set the required class and run the rest of your code.

Comment: @RafaelGadottiBachovas Okay tell me a little how can I do that? I think cookie does the same thing. It also stores information on client side.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948284/how-persistent-is-localstorage) may help you clarify....

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq When you toogle menu store value with localStorage.setItem('menuToogle', YOU_MENU_STATUS_HERE)... When you load new page get the value with localStorage.getItem('menuToogle') and show/hide your menu according to this value.

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq localStorage will store the value in the user memory and you can access it to define if menu is closed or opened.

Comment: @RafaelGadottiBachovas Thank you very much. localStorage helped me! It is so simple to use. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RafaelGadottiBachovas See my answer to my own question. How I solved it.

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq Nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used localStorage to solve my problem. It's really simple and easy way to store setting locally. I add these two lines.

**Here is my code:**

```
 localStorage.setItem('Menu', 'Mini');

 localStorage.setItem('Menu', 'Larg');
```

**Then I added script in my page like this:**

```
<script>
if (localStorage.Menu === 'Mini') {
    $("body").addClass('nav-sm');

} else {
    $("body").addClass('nav-md');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.cookie = "togglesetting=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2017 12:00:00 UTC";
```

You can put your setting information into any key value pattern in the cookie.

My suggestion is to put a json there and read the togglesetting key from cookies than set your toogle menu appropriately

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this earlier today for a website that I am building. My preferred method was to add a cookie check to the head. This adds a class to the html that you can attach styling to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)hasClosedMenu\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") == false) {
    document.documentElement.className += " menu-open "
  }
</script>
```

Below you will find the function that sets the cookie determining whether the menu is open or not.

```
$('.menu-toggle').on('click',function(){
  $('html').toggleClass('open-menu');
  if ($('html').hasClass('open-menu')){
    document.cookie = "hasClosedMenu=; max-age=0; domain="+window.location.hostname+"; path=/; ";
  } else {
    document.cookie = "hasClosedMenu=true; max-age=864000; domain="+window.location.hostname+"; path=/; ";
  }
});
```

I hope this helps.