# why is javascript localStorage not persistant and removes values

Tags: javascript, local-storage

when I refresh the browser all the values stored in localStorage are gone. is there a way to prevent the browser to delete it?

```
    localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", false);
```

thanks

Comment: thanks for not explaining why downvoting!

Comment: Are you in an incognito window? localStorage *is* persistent, that shouldn't be happening by default... Perhaps this question will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948284/how-persistent-is-localstorage

Comment: no I'm not in incognitio mode ...

Comment: added an example above

Comment: I have added some explanation on it

Comment: Are you sure it's getting deleted, have you looked in the Inspector and viewed localStorage?..  Also I assume your doing `getItem()` as well?

Comment: @Felix please don't whine about downvotes, you give us a bad name ;)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I don't whine, but If somebody do a downvote then there should be an explanation

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [When is localStorage cleared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537112/when-is-localstorage-cleared)

Comment: @Felix No. There is absolutely no requirement, recommendation or anything that encourages people to explain downvotes. Are you aware of the meta portion of the site? Start [reading here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777/576767). The general consensus about explaining downvotes is that we have strictly no reason to do it.

Comment: when You downvote a question there is a popUp or hint which reminds you to make a comment ... only a downvote does not improve anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage` is also known as Web Storage, HTML5 Storage, and DOM Storage.

`localStorage` is similar to `sessionStorage`, except that data stored in `localStorage` has no expiration time, but `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the browsing session ends (i.e. when the browser is closed).

`localStorage` is available on all browsers, but persistence is not consistently implemented. Furthermore `localStorage` can be cleared by user action.

In Firefox, `localStorage` is cleared when these three conditions are met:

1. user clears recent history,
2. cookies are selected to be cleared
3. time range is "Everything"

In Chrome, `localStorage` is cleared when these conditions are met:

1. clear browsing data,
2. "cookies and other site data" is selected,
3. `timeframe` is "from beginning of time".

In IE, to clear localStorage:

1. `Tools-->Internet Options`,
2. General tab,
3. delete browsing history on exit

In Safari:

1. Click Safari
2. Preferences
3. Select the Privacy tab
4. Click Remove all website data

Comment: Please vote to close as a dupe instead of plagiarising content from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37105645/519413)